# jQuery.ajax() uses current page URL instead of specified URL

Tags: jquery

If I make this call on a page such as index.php:

```
jQuery.ajax("keepalive.php");
```

jQuery makes a request for index.php instead of keepalive.php.

This request is only to keep a session going, so I don't care about the result.  According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), simply specifying a URL is all that is needed.  Any thoughts on why this doesn't work correctly?

Comment: my guess is you have server-side code redirecting your keepalive.php request to index.php.  Lots of frameworks and/or content management systems  do that...

Comment: @Crayon Violent, I assure you that is not the case, and even if it were, I would see such requests when analyzing with Fiddler.

Comment: @mu is too short, jQuery 1.8.14

Comment: Never mind, just found the problem....

Comment: @Brad, well I did say it was just a guess. I assumed you at least were using the latest version of jQuery. Beyond that, I'm not psychic, you didn't really say what all you tried or looked at.  Glad you got it sorted though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work only if you're using jquery >= 1.5.
For maximum compatibility, use the following:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'keepalive.php'
});
```

This code will run in any jquery version.
Hope this helps.